# Just bought an ultrawide monitor, but it looks borderline blury, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: font, displayport, 4k, display

So I either bought the wrong thing, or just don't know how to configure it correctly.  I bought a [Acer XR342CK bmijqphuzx](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1348231-REG/acer_um_cx2aa_002_34_wide_white_led.html/?lsft=BI%3A514&gclid=Cj0KCQjwiILsBRCGARIsAHKQWLNqjDV2bJisaXANOT1fJlc55OYjP5_-z_ht54fMKmkHHU4Pqeh5xrIaAoDQEALw_wcB) , and have it hooked up to a Macbook Pro w Touchbar 2016 via a Caldigit TS3 plus dock using displayport.

Basically the fonts looked jagged and borderline blurry.  At first I thought there was something wrong with my eyes and I kept squinting.  I missed with the font smoothing effects in MacOS and don't notice any changes.

Are these ultrawide monitors just not as high resolution as the retina or the 4k Monitors I'm currently used to ( I have an [HP Z27](https://store.hp.com/us/en/pdp/hp-z27-27-inch-4k-uhd-display) at work, and a [Dell 2715Q](http://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_display_projector/esuprt_display/dell-p2715q-monitor_user%27s%20guide_en-us.pdf) on my mac mini at home)

Thanks for the help, was looking forward to this super wide 34 inch for video editing, but I didn't expected it to be annoyingly less sharp.  I'm definitely open to the possibility that I've done something stupid!

Comment: From your links, it's not as high res as your others, 3440x1440 [which is 1440p or 2k, plus a bit of extra width compared to standard 2560x1440] The other two are 3840 x 2160. That's quite a difference on what is essentially the 'same size screen' [plus width]

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense! Is there an ultra wide that has that same resolution?

Comment: You'd need 5120 x 2160 ultrawide - but idk if the Mac will be able to run it. Max is quoted at 4096 x 2304

Comment: Sounds like a better bet is a 32 inch 4k monitor like this one https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1434507-REG/dell_u3219q_ultrasharp_32_4k.html/reviews

Comment: bmijqphuzx? That's the oddest model name / identifier I've ever seen.

Comment: @IconDaemon HP has some pretty weird model names too, like the [HP Notebook 17-by0020ds](https://www8.hp.com/us/en/laptops/product-details/28967620).

Comment: @IconDaemon believe me, it made it hard just to figure out which version I was actually getting.  Can't believe any company would choose to do that on purpose